# How to retrieve AFL from mastercard?

Tags: emv, contactless-smartcard, mastercard

I'm trying to read some data like track 2 from mastercard contactless. But the PDOL not returned after select AID command, so how can I construct GPO to read AFL? to initiate read records comnand. If there is any advice?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not seem programming related and does not show what you have already done yourself. You might want to improve it a little. 

Answer to your question is also directly available in the specification - you might want to read it first as it will clarify many things for you. PDOL is an optional data element and specification indicates how to build GPO command in chapters 6.5.8.3 and 10.1 of Book 3.

Answer (score 1):

I trird to send GPO command without PDOL like this: "80A80000028300" and then I can read AFL in response.